# reCAPTCHA v2 Occasional Leaks

Tags: recaptcha

I'm using v2 to protect a registration form from spam, but there are still occasional spam registrations happening on some days, like yesterday. Today, though, there were over 70 spam registrations and the reCAPTCHA stats for yesterday does not show any requests:
[image]
I changed the security preference to "most secure", let's see if this will give any improvements or whether I'll have to upgrade to reCAPTCHA v3.
[image]